# Custom Font Rendering Incorrectly in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Trying to use a custom font with Android Studios (Inconsolata), but Android Studio is just rendering it as a bunch of As. Is there any fix to this?

[image: no description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82969) with several possible workarounds. One option is to configure Android Studio to run under JDK 7 or JDK 8 by editing Info.plist and changing the JVMVersion, as described in the last comment to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest version of Android Studio fixed this issue.